# Paypal functionality before download

Tags: android, paypal

I am working in android. I am designing a program to download a file from my http server. before download the file payment should be done.

this is my first layout:-
[image]

when i click on on paypal button this paypal site is opened:-

[image]

so i want to know that after make payment is this site return something on the basis of that i can allow or donot allow user to download.

i want to know that user has paid something or not ? please help me in this paypal concept in android.

Thank you  in advance...

Comment: Did you look at the Paypal API documentation? https://cms.paypal.com/us/cgi-bin/?cmd=_render-content&content_ID=developer/howto_gateway_payflowgateway

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have done this by taking help from a from a book.

This is the code which is used to the solution for my question:-

@Override

```
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {

switch(resultCode) {

case Activity.RESULT_OK:

//The payment succeeded



Toast.makeText(this,"Payment has done successfully",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

//Tell the user their payment succeeded
```

break;

```
case Activity.RESULT_CANCELED:


    Toast.makeText(this,"Payment has cancled",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
break;

case PayPalActivity.RESULT_FAILURE:

    flag=false;
    Toast.makeText(this,"Sorry Payment failed",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
```